# Derivative $(1-x)^{-2}$

Tags: derivatives

I'm getting answer of $\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$ , but online calculators suggest it's $\frac{-2}{(1-x)^3}$. I've tried it as $(1-x)^{-2}$, which results $-2*(1-x)*-1 = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$. Same result with $(\frac{f}{g})'=\frac{(f'*g-f*g')}{g^2}$ . Any help please?

Comment: Your answer is correct : $((1-x)^{-2})'=-2(1-x)^{-3}\cdot (1-x)'=2(1-x)^{-3}.$

Comment: Those calculators seem to be defective.

Comment: Could you give the link to the calculator you used ? This could be very interesting for our community. Thanks.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+%28+%281-x%29^%28-2%29+%29) agrees with your answer, noting that $(1-x)^3 = -(x-1)^3$.  Perhaps the calculator you used as well reversed the order of the $x$ and the $1$.

Answer (score 1):

after the power and the chaine rule you will get $$-2(1-x)^{-3}(-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: x \mapsto 1 - x$ and $g: u \mapsto u^{-2}.$ Let $h: x \overset{f}{\mapsto} 1-x =: u \overset{g}{\mapsto} u^{-2}.$ Then $h'(x) = -2u^{-3}\big|_{u = 1-x}\cdot (-1) = 2(1-x)^{-3}.$

So yes, you are correct there.